# display incorrect password message

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, c#-4.0, razor

I have below form written in mvc3 razor. I want to display a message when user has entered incorrect password. I have placed a label to display message but dont know how to accomplish show/hide in mvc. Please help.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    < div>
    < fieldset>
        <legend > User Information </legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Password")

            @Html.TextBox("password")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password)
            @Html.Label("Incorrect Password")
        </div>
        <p>
            @Html.Hidden("tab", ViewData["tab"])
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

Comment: A note about security: Do you think it's wise to prompt the user when s/he has entered **only** an incorrect password? You give away that the user exists on your application.

Comment: Note that it's important to not do your password validation client-side.  I'm not entirely sure where razor does its validations, but if they're server-side, you may just be able to get away with a well-constructed if statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the controller action that is supposed to validate the credentials you could add a modelstate error:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("password", "The username or password is incorrect");
```

Create a new ASP.NET MVC application using the built-in wizard in Visual Studio and navigate to `~/Controller/AccountController.cs`. Then look at the `LogOn` POST action. It adds a general modelstate error when the credentials are invalid:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
```

and this error is displayed using a ValidationSummary helper inside the view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```